# Capital city that starts with "a", and ends with "a". Doesn't matter if letter "a" is uppercase or lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, character

Start with a, and ends with a. I have been trying to output capital cities that start and end with the letter "a". Doesn't matter if they start with capital "A"

```
capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')
```

This is my code:

```
for elem in capitals:
    elem = elem.lower()
    ["".join(j for j in i if j not in string.punctuation) for i in capitals]
    if (len(elem) >=4 and elem.endswith(elem[0])):
        print(elem)
```

My output is:

```
andorra la vella
saint john's
asmara
addis ababa
accra
saint george's
nur-sultan
abuja
oslo
warsaw
apia
ankara
tashkent
```

My expected output is:

```
andorra la vella
asmara
addis ababa
accra
abuja
apia
ankara
```

Comment: So why aren't you checking if the string starts and ends with 'a'? You apparently know about `endswith`. There's also `startswith`.

Comment: In your own words, what does `elem.endswith(elem[0])` mean?

Comment: Why do you have the line `["".join(j for j in i if j not in string.punctuation) for i in capitals]` in the middle of your loop, which does nothing, since you're not assigning the output to anything? Also, why not just print out `elem`s where `startswith('a')` and `endswith('a')` are `True`?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the input. Im new to this.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't check if the capital starts with 'a'. I also assumed you want to filter out punctuation based on your code, so this is what I ended up with:

```
import string

for elem in capitals:
    elem = elem.lower()
    for punct in string.punctuation:
        elem = elem.replace(punct, '')
    if elem.startswith('a') and elem.endswith('a'):
        print(elem)
```

Comment: `elem.replace(punct, '')` achieves nothing if you neglect the return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem in capitals:
    elem = elem.lower()
    if (elem.startswith('a') and elem.endswith('a')):
        print(elem)
```